# connect dbeaver using existing local DSN

Tags: postgresql, odbc, dsn, dbeaver

I have a machine with a local system DSN configured.
This connection points to a PostgreSQL database.
This works well (BO  is using it)

Can I use this existing local DSN to connect dbeaver to this PostgreSQL Database?
I do not know the password of the database, hence my hope of using the already configured and working DSN.

Comment: DBeaver is a Java application, so it needs a JDBC driver. You can't use ODBC connections with Java/JDBC

Comment: Put that as an answer so you can have credit where it is due?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not solve this, used PostgreSQL drivers